# Debug and run mode in Jupyter

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, pdb, ipdb

Like in matlab, is there a possiblity in Jupyter to run a function in debug mode where execution is suspended at breakpoints and in run mode the function ignores the breakpoints?
In a simple example like

```
from IPython.core.debugger import set_trace

def debug(y):
    x = 10
    x = x + y 
    set_trace()
    for i in range(10):
        x = x+i
    return x

debug(10)
```

is it possible that we call the function such that the set_trace is ignored and function is run normally?

The reason I want to have this is that in my function I have placed a lot of set traces and when I just want to run without the traces I need to comment all the set traces. Is there an easier way?

Comment: Have you considered [Spyder](https://pythonhosted.org/spyder/)? It has comparable interface as Matlab.

Comment: I am actually using notebook for my work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know of a way you can do this with Jupyter directly, but what you could do is monkey patch `set_trace()` out by like this (I'd recommend putting this in its own cell so you can re-run it for when you want to turn debugging back on):

```
from IPython.core.debugger import set_trace
debug_mode = False #switch this to True if you want debugging back on
if not debug_mode:
  def pass_func():
    pass
  set_trace = pass_func
```

What this does is rebind the name `set_trace` to be a function that simply does nothing, so every time `set_trace()` is called, it will just `pass`.

If you want the debugging back on, just switch the `debug_mode` flag to `True` and re-run the cell. This will then rebind the name `set_trace` to be the `set_trace` imported from `IPython.core.debugger`.

Comment: Works for me! Thanks :)